# How do you inject a mocked angular service that is used in the app.run function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, mocking

I have added some logic for authentication in my angular app and the initial the call to the service wrapping the webapi is executed in the app.run function, like this:

```
myApp.run(function ($rootScope, $location, myService) {

myService.getCurrentUser().then(function (promise) {
    //reroute to either access denied or the start page when access is verified.

});

// register listener to watch route changes
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {

    //check access
}); 
});
```

After this all my unit tests broke, since I don't know how to inject the mocked version of myService before creating the app module. I've factored out the service and the mocked service in a seperate module so I can create it before creating the actual app. Like this:

```
   angular.mock.module('ServiceModule');

    angular.mock.module('EArkivApp', function ($provide, myMockedService) {
        $provide.value('myService', myMockedService);
    });
```

This is not working however, it complains that "myMockedService" (which is part of the ServiceModule) is an unkown provider. Do you have any good suggestions of how I should solve this?

Comment: I suppose you can refer to this article about [angular module lazy loading](http://blog.getelementsbyidea.com/load-a-module-on-demand-with-angularjs/) for help

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide us for a jsfiddle?
Meanwhile, if you are using Karma then you can use something like this:

```
/*global  describe, beforeEach, module, inject, it, expect*/
describe('Controller: MyCtrl', function () {
  'use strict';
  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  var MyCtrl,
      scope,
      modalInstance;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, myMockedService) {
     scope = $rootScope.$new();
      modalInstance = _$modal_.open({
              templateUrl: 'views/my-template.html'
          });
      MyCtrl = $controller('MyCtrl', {
          $scope: scope, 
          $myMockedService: myMockedService
      });
  }));

  it('should be true', function () {
      expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

I learned this by using Yeoman scaffolding, by the way :)